# Adding new element into a fixed array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I did search on internet, but still don't understand, so I ask this question here.

in the small program below, I created two tour instance, all I want to do is putting tour[2] in without changing "Tour tour[]=new Tour[2];".

A lot of people recommend ArrayList, but I don't know how to do it in this code.

```
class Test{
public static void main(String args[]){

    class Tour{
        private String tourId;
        private String tourDescription;
        private double tourFee;
        private int numOfBooking;

        public Tour(String tourId,String tourDescription,double tourFee){
            this.tourId=tourId;
            this.tourDescription=tourDescription;
            this.tourFee=tourFee;
        }

        public void print(){
            System.out.println("ID:"+this.tourId);
            System.out.println("Desc:"+this.tourDescription);
            System.out.println("Fee:"+this.tourFee);
        }
    }


    Tour tour[]=new Tour[2];
    tour[0]=new Tour("AB001","TOUR1",100);
    tour[1]=new Tour("AB002","TOUR2",200);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered, arrays are indeed fixed length, and as such I would definitely recommend an `ArrayList`. Use it like this...

```
ArrayList<Tour> tours = new ArrayList<Tour>();
tours.add(new Tour("AB001","TOUR1",100));
tours.add(new Tour("AB002","TOUR2",200));
```

Every time you want to add a new Tour, just call `tours.add()` again.

Comment: the problem is, the actual code is longer than this, and have a different functions, if I change the code like you said, I think I need to change most of the program?

Comment: You don't have much of a choice.  You _can't_ change the length of an array.

Comment: Yeah its a bit annoying, but once you know how to do it, you'll remember it from now on, and you'll never create the same problem again :-) If you've got a lot of them, try using find/replace in your editor so that you minimise the number of changes.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an array in java like `Tour tour[] = new Tour[2]` this means you can only add 2 elements to it.

To implement this using an ArrayList you would:

In you import statements add

```
import java.util.ArrayList
```

Then replace your array code with this

```
ArrayList<Tour> tour = new ArrayList<Tour>();
tour.add(new Tour("AB001", "TOUR1", 100);
tour.add(new Tour("AB002", "TOUR2", 200);
tour.add(new Tour("AB003", "TOUR3", 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to add a tour[2], then your array needs three elements, right?

Otherwise:

```
List<Tour> tour = new ArrayList<Tour>();
tour.add(new Tour("AB001", "TOUR1", 100);
tour.add(new Tour("AB002", "TOUR2", 200);
tour.add(new Tour("AB003", "TOUR3", 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it in with arrays, since their length are fixed. 

Your question pretty much shows the alternatives already:

1. Use an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)
2. Create a new instacne of the array

The ArrayList is actually an implementation of a [dynamic array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) in java, and this is most likely what you actually want.

Instantiate it with a default constructor, and add elements with [`ArrayList.add(index,element)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29) to add elements in specific location or with [`ArrayList.add(element)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29) to append elements.

code snap:

```
List<Tour> tours = new ArrayList<Tour>();
tours.add(new Tour("AB001","TOUR1",100));
tours.add(new Tour("AB001","TOUR1",100));
```

You can keep appending elements using `ArrayList.add(element)`

Answer (score 0):

As your array scenario is impossible, here's how to do the same process with an array list:

```
ArrayList<Tour> tours = new ArrayList<Tour>();
tours.add(new Tour("AB001","TOUR1",100));
tours.add(new Tour("AB002","TOUR2",200));
tours.add(/*another tour, and so forth*/);
// to convert to a Tour[], use the following:
Tour[] tourArray = tours.toArray(new Tour[tours.size()]);
```

ArrayList's are extremely useful in cases where the size of the data set is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

using array list is simple, 
you have this code :

```
Tour tour[]=new Tour[2];
tour[0]=new Tour("AB001","TOUR1",100);
tour[1]=new Tour("AB002","TOUR2",200);
```

replace it with this :

```
ArrayList<Tour> tours = new ArrayList<Tour>();
tours.add(new Tour("AB001","TOUR1",100));
tours.add(new Tour("AB002","TOUR2",200));
```

to get elements arrayList , simply use 
 tour.get( index ) ;

Answer (score 0):

They are right about the ArrayList; use it like this:

```
List<Tour> tours = new ArrayList<Tour>();
tours.add(new Tour("AB001","TOUR1",100));
tours.add(new Tour("AB002","TOUR2",200));
```

you will need to import java.util.*

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible unless assigned new. Because primitive arrays are not expandable.
Alternatively you can use collections to dynamically add a new object to the list.
An example is shown below:

```
List<Tour> tourList = new ArrayList<Tour>( 10 );  
tourList.add( 0, new Tour( "AB001", "TOUR1", 100 ) ); // add at first    
tourList.add( 1, new Tour( "AB002", "TOUR2", 200 ) ); // add next to first
```

This way you can add any number of `Tour` instances at any position of the list.
And you may want to convert the `tourList` back to a primitive array of `Tour`
For that you need following code:

```
Tour [] toursArray = new Tour[ tourList.size() ];
tourList.toArray( toursArray );
```